# ASCII Characters in Links Producing 404 Errors

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string, ascii

I used to have a query string ?q= in all my urls. I now have these urls redirecting to the alias name.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$(.*) /%1? [R=301,L,NE]`

Unfortunately other websites link to pages on my website in this manner www.example.com/%3Fq%3Dfaqs. I changed over all the links on my site to absolute but somehow google has indexed hundreds of pages that look like www.example.com/%3Fq%3Dfaqs?q=contact or www.example.com/%3Fq%3Dfaqs%3Fq%3Dcontact.
Is there a way I can rewrite these ASCII codes back to the symbols using htaccess or some other method?

Comment: The second rule makes no sense! You are looking for a string after the end.

Comment: Are you talking about this? '^q=(.*)$' What should it be? This code works to take my urls from example.com/?q=faqs to example.com/faqs but doesn't work when these symbols are replaced with %3F and %3D.

Comment: No this part here: ^$(.*) Anyway at the moment i don't understand how that url encoded URLs are produced.

Comment: They're coming from seo websites like this semisland.com/uscooler.com They're not even links but google is following them. I went from 200 indexed pages on my site to over 1,000 (not good).

Comment: SEO websites? You mean a link farm wich puts you higher in the ranking? Simply don't do that! That is cheating.

Comment: No, we don't use any services. It's websites that analyze different websites for seo purposes. They scan your site without you asking and often return invalid or abbreviated urls which search engines follow.

Comment: I solved this by writing lines like Redirect 301 /?q=faqs http://www.example.com/?q=faqs This redirected /%3Fq%3Dfaqs to /?q=faqs which redirected to /faqs. Probably not the best way to do it, but it works.

Comment: Write this as an answer this may help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing lines like `Redirect 301 /?q=faqs example.com/?q=faqs` This redirected /%3Fq%3Dfaqs to /?q=faqs which redirected to /faqs. Probably not the best way to do it, but it works.